# How to change back to original element from cloned one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

textbox is changed to become link tag after clone() and moved to the top. Now when the cloned item is removed, the item append back into the below div where it came from. This works fine, but instead of appending back in the cloned form, I wish it to be released from changes made by clone()(back to original form NOT order).

ORIGINAL ELEMENT:
[image]

```
$("#sub").append("<div class='sub row clone_this' id='"+globalStore.data[i].subid+"' ><div class='small-5 medium-3 large-3 columns'><input type='text' onfocusout='getText("+globalStore.data[i].subid+")' class='text_"+globalStore.data[i].subid+"' placeholder='RM'></div><div class='small-7 medium-7 large-7 columns'>"+globalStore.data[i].subname+"</div><div class='small-2 end medium-2 large-2 columns cr'></div></div>");
```

CLONE:
[image]

```
function getText(param)
{
  var clony = $("div.clone_this#"+param).remove().clone(true, true).insertBefore("#sub");
  var price = $("input[type=text].text_"+param).val();
 // alert(price);
  clony.find('input[type=text]').replaceWith("<a href='ch'><span class='green' style='font-style:italic;'>RM "+price+"</span></a>");
   clony.find('.cr').append("<a href='' onclick=removeThis('"+param+"')><img src='/register/cross.png'></a>");

}
```

WHEN REMOVE LINK CLICKED ON THE CLONED ITEM
[image]

```
function removeThis(param)
{
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $("div.clone_this#"+param).remove().appendTo("#sub");
     //find("a[href=ch]").replaceWith("input[type=text]")
     return false;
}
```

Comment: You are **`removing`** and then trying to **`append`** element which has been already **removed**. Instead of `removing` try [**`detach`**](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)ing the element and then you can use `appendTo` on that.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, remove() is working here, just that I want get back the original form of element.

Comment: You cannot use `appendTo` once you `remove`.. `remove` completely removes it from `DOM`

Comment: Can you create a problem `fiddle`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, I understood now, could you tell me, say I use detach(), how to replace just the <a href='ch'>price</a> into <input type='text' val='+price+' /> ?

Comment: I have some confusion on this.. See this line `$("div.clone_this#"+param).remove().clone(true,true)..` again you are trying to `clone` after `remove`.. Not sure how this works for you.. So it will be good if post some `html` too or a better one to create sample problem `fiddle`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Please don't get confused, probably get replace with detach().. No html used, all generated in jquery..for fiddle, I would like to but seriously busy

Comment: Am trying to understand but this actually gives me no idea on when and where you call `getText` also when that `$("#sub").append` happening?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, just forget the function names. PLease refer to my posts, I updated with picture in each stage as to describe what happens before , after clone and when remove clicked. So just help me, on how to change the link form of element back to textbox when remove is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I updated my remove function as follow and it works:

```
function removeThis(param)
{
     event.preventDefault(); 


     $("div.clone_this#"+param).detach().appendTo("#sub");
     var price = $("a[href=ch]").text();
     $("div.clone_this#"+param).find($("a[href=ch]").text(price)).replaceWith("<input type='text' onfocusout='getText("+param+")' class='text_"+param+"' val='"+price+"' placeholder='RM'>");

     $("div.clone_this#"+param).find("a[href=del]").remove();
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.end()` to move to previous chain element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#element')
    .find('.child')
    .css({
      'background-color': '#ddd'
    })
    .end()
    .css({
      'background-color': '#787878'
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element">
  TEXT 1
  <div class="child">
    TEXT 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does it answers the problem?

Comment: @Justinas, I tried something like this:  $("div.clone_this#"+param).remove().find("a[href=ch]").end().replaceWith("input[type=text]").appendTo("#sub");

Comment: This, replaces that one link with multiple textboxes and only that, the subject name not shown. But I think end() is a good idea, just don't know how to use it wisely here